# How do I move an iPhoto '11 book project from one mac to another

Tags: photos.app, migration

I have iPhoto '11 with Photostream set up on my Mac Mini and on my Macbook Pro. I'm getting rid of the macbook pro, but have a photo book I've been working on on it that I want to move over to my Mac Mini (to finish up the work and print it). Is there a way to do this? I have the same pictures on both computers, I just can figure out how to move the project...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only way to move a project is to [move the Library](http://support.apple.com/kb/PH2506) that contains it. There is no way to move a book from one Library to another.